# Scala: reduceLeft with String

Tags: scala

I have a list of Integers and I want to make a String of it.

```
var xs = list(1,2,3,4,5)
(xs foldLeft "") (_+_)               // String = 12345
```

with foldLeft it works perfect, but my question is does it also work with reduceLeft? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It cannot work this way with `reduceLeft`. Informally you can view `reduceLeft` as a special case of `foldLeft` where the accumulated value is of the same type as the collection's elements. Because in your case the element type is `Int` and the accumulated value is `String`, there is no way to use `reduceLeft` in the way you used `foldLeft`.

However in this specific case you can simply convert all your `Int` elements to `String` up front, and then reduce:

```
scala> xs.map(_.toString) reduceLeft(_+_)
res5: String = 12345
```

Note that this will throw an exception if the list is empty. This is another difference with `foldLeft`, which handles the empty case just fine (because it has an explicit starting value).
This is also less efficient because we create a whole new collection (of strings) just to reduce it on the spot.
All in all, `foldLeft` is a much better choice here.

Answer (score 4):

It takes a little bit of work to make sure the types are understood correctly. Expanding them, though, you could use something like:

```
(xs reduceLeft ((a: Any, b: Int) => a + b.toString)).toString
```